# How to change the look of the controls for this rotating banner

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to change the look of the controls for this rotating banner. They are currently just grey (and the current/selected one is black). I want the dots to be white with a grey outline (and the selected/current one to be orange with a grey outline).

Here's the css (I believe the selector is: .rslides_tabs a):

```
.rslides_container
{
    position: relative;
}

.rslides
{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

    .rslides li
    {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .rslides li:first-child
    {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

        .rslides img
        {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            max-width:  100%;
            border: 0;
        }

    .rslides_tabs
    {
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .rslides_tabs li
        {
            display: inline;
            float: none;
            _float: left;
            *float: left;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

            .rslides_tabs a
            {
                text-indent: -9999px;
                overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
                -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                border-radius: 15px;
                -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                background: #ccc;
                display: inline-block;
                _display: block;
                *display: block;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                width: 9px;
                height: 9px;
            }

            .rslides_tabs .rslides_here a
            {
                background: #222;
            }

    .rslides_nav
    {
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #000;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-opacity: 0.7;
        -moz-opacity: 0.7;
        -o-opacity: 0.7;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        opacity: 0.7;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 61px;
        width: 38px;
        background: transparent url( '../images/responsiveslides.gif' ) no-repeat left top;
        margin-top: -45px;
    }

    .rslides_nav:active,
    .rslides_nav:hover
    {
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
        -o-opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .rslides_nav.next
    {
        left: auto;
        background-position: right top;
        right: 0;
    }
```

If you need any more code to help me out, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a
```

Is the one where you currently are

```
.rslides_tabs a
```

Has the value of the dot that is not selected.

Change the background property to the color you want.

Comment: Changing the color property has no effect on them. Not sure why.

Comment: Sorry i mean change the background property to a color like #FF0000; for red.

Comment: Did the above work? Cause i changed the background color and it changed on my browser.

Comment: change all 3 box-shadow properties of .rslides_tabs a in the rgb() to the colour. NOTE: This is RGB code.. so use numbers.

Comment: For some reason it's not working (the background color change isn't displaying on the site either).

Comment: You made a new class... you should edit the current CSS. not make a new line. Search your code for .rslides_tabs .rslides_here a in ResponsiveMenu10.css or add !important behind your current class if you wish to keep it... example : background: #F00 !important;

Answer (score 2):

```
.rslides_tabs a {
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid grey;
//here goes your style
}

.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a {
  //here goes your style for the selected one
}
```

Comment: Tried 

.rslides_tabs a {
color:#fff;
}

.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a {
    background: url('image Url here') no-repeat;
}

...no change to the page.

Comment: Awesome. That works for changing the color of the dot! Thank you. Any idea how I can get a grey border/outline around the dot?

Comment: For some reason it's not working (the background color change isn't displaying on the site either).

Comment: try add !important to the background-color.
background-color:red !important;